# setup.py adding options (aka setup.py --enable-feature )

Tags: python, packaging, distutils

I'm looking for a way to include some feature in a python (extension) module in installation phase.

In a practical manner:

I have a python library that has 2 implementations of the same function, one internal (slow) and one that depends from an external library (fast, in C).

I want that this library is optional and can be activated at compile/install time using a flag like:

```
python setup.py install # (it doesn't include the fast library)
python setup.py --enable-fast install
```

I have to use Distutils, however all solution are well accepted!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, each of them deserves accepted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of exactly what you want is the [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org)'s [cextensions](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/06Migration#CExtensionsforResultFetching), which are there specifically for the same purpose - faster C implementation. In order to see how SA implemented it you need to look at 2 files:

1) [setup.py](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/browser/setup.py). As you can see from the extract below, they handle the cases with `setuptools` and `distutils`:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup, Extension, Feature
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup, Extension
    Feature = None
```

Later there is a check `if Feature:` and the extension is configured properly for each case using variable `extra`, which is later added to the `setup()` function.

2) [base.py](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/browser/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py): here look at how `BaseRowProxy` is defined:

```
try:
    from sqlalchemy.cresultproxy import BaseRowProxy
except ImportError:
    class BaseRowProxy(object):
        #....
```

So basically once C extensions are installed (using `--with-cextensions` flag during setup), the C implementation will be used. Otherwise, pure Python implementation of the class/function is used.

Answer (score 4):

The docs for distutils include [a section on extending the standard functionality](http://docs.python.org/distutils/extending.html). The relevant suggestion seems to be to subclass the relevant classes from the `distutils.command.*` modules (such as `build_py` or `install`) and tell `setup` to use your new versions (through the `cmdclass` argument, which is a dictionary mapping commands to classes which are to be used to execute them). See the source of any of the command classes (e.g. [the install command](http://bitbucket.org/carljm/python-distutils/src/tip/command/install.py#cl-120)) to get a good idea of what one has to do to add a new option.